# Mock method return value with read only property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, moq

I wish to test a method which queries a third-party library. The library returns an object with a `IReadOnlyCollection` property.

There is no constructor to set the value of the property and the object has no interface for me to mock.

I have used `Moq` to mock the interface for the service that I call, but I can't create a mocked return value as I can't set the property.

```
public interface IHitService {
    public Hit GetHit();
}

public class Hit {
    public Hit() {
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Result { get; }
}

public class TestingClass {
    public void MyTest() {
        Hit hit = new Hit() {
            // cannot set this property
            Result = new List<string>() { "hello","goodbye" };
        }

        Mock<IHitService> service = new Mock<IHitService>();
        service.Setup(c => c.GetHit).Returns(hit);
    }
}
```

What would be the best way for me to generate the return value to test my method? Wrapping the object with a `new` property to hide the base does not work.

Comment: how does it normally get set?

Comment: and does it matter if its not set? its a third party thing.  You don't normally test that, just your own code

Comment: We manipulate the data in the method I am testing. It calls `GetHit()` and works on the data in the `Result` collection. The property was originally an `IEnumerable` but the latest version has changed it to a `ReadOnlyCollection`. I am not sure how it is set in the library. That's a good idea, I will check the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unit-test frameworks that allow you to change the behavior of a concrete object, for example in this case i used Typemock Isolator to try and solve your issue, it allows you to change the the return value of the result property so can "set" for your test without changing your code or adding extra code:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    List<string> s = new List<string> { "sfas", "asfsa", "blbba" };
    var hit = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<Hit>();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => hit.Result).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(s);
}
```

In this test i mocked the Hit class and modified the return value of the Result property to a list of strings i created.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to test a third-party library, it would be a better idea to create your own abstraction (interface) and rely on that for both testing and real code:

```
public interface IHitService
{
    IHit GetHit();
}

public interface IHit
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> Result { get; }
}
```

In your application code, you can create a simple wrapper class that implements `IHit` by delegating to the concrete third-party class. Now you can test the interface by mocking it as needed.

Comment: This looks like my option. It's not a simple class, but the work needs to be done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure, happy to help. This can also be a test smell that you're testing at too low of a level. In many cases, it might make more sense to test _your_ service interfaces that may consume the library, rather than testing/mocking the library calls themselves.

Comment: Yeah, this is a tricky situation where depending on the `Result` different things happen so I need to control the input object - and then the developer changes the access level on me!

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you can't change 3rd party code, build an adapter to it and use your own abstraction :-

```
public interface IHit
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> Result { get; }
}

public interface IHitService
{
    IHit GetHit();
}

public class HitAdapter : IHit
{
    private Hit _hit;

    public HitAdapter(Hit hit)
    {
        _hit = hit;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Result => _hit.Result;
}


public class TestingClass
{
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var hitMock =  new Mock<IHit>();
        hitMock.Setup(c => c.Result).Returns<IReadOnlyCollection<string>>(x => new List<string>() {"hello", "goodbye"});
        var service = new Mock<IHitService>();
        service.Setup(c => c.GetHit()).Returns<IHit>(x => hitMock.Object);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like my option. It's not a simple class, but the work needs to be done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you have resharper, it takes a LOT of the donkey work out of generating the delegating adapter